# Setting default value for global variable if undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

**Objective**

Pass the `role (e.g. admin)` of a `user` to all my `view templates` without having to do it in each individual route.

**What I'm trying**

Adding user roles (called with `req.oidc.user...`) as a `res.local` in `app.js`.

**Code** (app.js)

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.role = req.oidc.user['https://localhost:3000.com/roles'] ?? "null"
})
```

**Problem**

I was hoping the `?? "null"` would add a value of "null" to the roles when a user is not logged in so I can handle conditional logic in the templates with

```
'if !role === 'admin' do x.
```

Instead, I'm just getting an error of `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'https://localhost:3000.com/roles')` (understandable as there's nothing there when not logged in!)

Is there a better way to pass a values that will be undefined until a user logs in to my views without doing the below in every single route in `(controller.js)`:

```
index = (req, res) => {
  res.render("index", {
    role: req.oidc.user['https://localhost:3000.com/roles'],
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've said, your code is trying to read a value from a variable that might be `undefined`.

You can either use a condition to check wether `req.oidc.user` exists before reading from it or have [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) in order to "short-circuit" the expression to `undefined` without causing an error.

This is your code with optional chaining:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.locals.role = req.oidc.user?.['https://localhost:3000.com/roles'] ?? "null";
});
```

Side note, I suggest not using `"null"` as your default value. Maybe use an empty string (`""`) which is also a [falsy value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy).

Comment: the optional chaining worked perfectly for my use case thanks